# Spring Data - Query by List

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

Is it possible to make a List Query that results in one value? The following does not work. The result is null. The combination of optionValues will result in one variant. 
Here is my Data:

OptionValues

```
[
  {
   "id" : "5cc248eeaa4a4f7b35454079",
    "optionType" : {
         "id" : "5cc2301ab2c4cea611ceb13d",
         "name" : "size",
         "title" : "Size"
    },
    "value" : "S"
  }
]
```

Variant

```
{
    "id" : "5cc24361b2c4cea611cee8c9,
    "optionValues" : [
    {
        "id" : "5cc248eeaa4a4f7b35454079",
        "optionType" : {
            "id" : "5cc2301ab2c4cea611ceb13d",
            "name" : "size",
            "title" : "Size"
        },
        "value" : "S"
    }
     ],
    "price" : 10.99
}
```

Variant Model

```
@Data
@Document   
public class Variant extends StoreEntity {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @DBRef
    private List<OptionValue> optionValues;
    ...
}
```

OptionValues Model

```
@Data
@Document
public class OptionValue {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @DBRef
    private OptionType optionType;
    private String value;
}
```

OptionType Model

```
@Data
@Document
public class OptionValue {
    @Id
        private String id;
    private String name;
    private String title;
}
```

Variant Repository

```
Variant findByOptionValues(List<OptionValue> optionValues);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variant findByOptionValuesIn(List optionValues);